# Remove characters at end of each element

Tags: tcl

I have a problem with removing characters in TCL.

I have a variable that contains 3 elements:

```
> puts $scan_ports
scan_clkvco_clk scan_clkvco_div_2_clk scan_clkin_clk
```

And I would like to save in another variable, those same 3 elements, but removing the `_clk` at the end of each element.

This is what I have tried:

```
regsub -all "_clk" $scan_ports "" scan_groups
```

But it removes all `_clk` matches

The expected result should be:

```
puts $scan_groups
> scan_clkvco scan_clkvco_div_2 scan_clkin
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you haven't already subjected the values held by `scan_ports` to a treatment as a Tcl list, you might also want to consider mapping out the suffix using [`string map`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34):

```
string map {"_clk " " "} "$scan_ports "
```

If already a list, or meant to be used as a list in a subsequent step, then Donal's solution is likely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [end of word anchor](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M75):

```
regsub -all {_clk\M} $scan_ports "" scan_groups
# scan_clkvco scan_clkvco_div_2 scan_clkin
```

Note: it's usually also better to use braces with re's.

Answer (score 0):

This is where `lmap` can help, and you *really* ought to be using an anchored match.

```
lmap sp $scan_ports {regsub {_clk$} $sp ""}
```

Doing it like this means that it won't do weird things with elements like `foo_clk_bar_clk boo_clk`.